# LARAVEL SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'phone_number' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I started new project on Laravel and wanted to add 2 extra columns to User table (phone_number, position). But when I try to register I have this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'phone_number' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Lidija, lidija@gmail.com, $2y$10$/BQju2korC4YOm.6yCb2i.sOoQQJTgzEyklrHPfJPF1XQwx86Vyky, 2020-10-09 15:35:36, 2020-10-09 15:35:36))

I did migrate tables. Maybe there is something wrong with **input values** in blade.php?

User model:
[image]

My User migration:
[image]

UserController:
[image]

Blade.php:
[image]

I did `php artisan optimize`, didn't help. Also, I tried `dd($request->all())` in the Store method to see what's there, but it showed nothing, just this error 1364 again.

What could be the problem?

Comment: So you also have a column called `phone_number` in that table. BUT you are not setting a value for that column!! So either set a phone number OR make the column in the database allowed to be blank

Comment: Add: "blank" means nullable in this case.

Comment: Set Default NULL otherwise pass phone number in request.

Comment: @RiggsFolly but I have inputs in my view..

Comment: @BhargavVariya I know I can make it default in migration, but I want to pass the value through my view. I showed inputs in screenshot. something wrong with my inputs?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden I use composer require laravel/jetstream, php artisan jetstream:install livewire. It is something new, 8 months earlier when I used Laravel, there was not such thing

Comment: In future, please ensure you add code and error messages to your question. Pictures are not particularly helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `route("register")` probably does not go through `UserController@store`. Check output of `artisan route:list` to see what controller and method handle this route.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either set a default value for `phone_number` (like `null` for example), or pass it with the arguments, otherwise, your requests will always fail.

Change your migration to something like this in order to make phone_number null if not passed as an argument.

`$table->integer('phone_number')->unique()->nullable();`

Comment: Yes, I can do nullable, but this way I have no value. I pass arguments through the form, but it seems like it does not work, because in both ways I do not get argument from the form

Comment: for debugging, try returning the whole request and see if the server does even get the phone_number with the request, if not, there is likely a problem with your blade template.